# How do you resolve ambiguous aliases in MySQL to the current table's definitions

Tags: mysql, sql, alias, self, ambiguity

I was wondering if MySQL has some kind of default alias for the current table you are building (like 'self' in SmallTalk or 'this' in Java).  For instance:

```
SELECT 
SUM(revenue) AS revenue,
SUM(units) AS units,
SUM(revenue)/SUM(units) AS revPerUnit,
-- I want to replace the above line with the below line:
self.revenue/self.units AS revPerUnit2
FROM inputTable;
```

I know that I could just use unabiguous aliases, but I want to know if there is a way to specify that you want the current table's alias when there exists an ambiguous definition.

Comment: Nope. What's wrong with just using a short one like `users` goes to `u`, etc?

Comment: In the event that you're creating a table you may want descriptive field names, but I would largely agree with you for ad hoc queries.

Comment: How would the sql know what the "CURRENT"  table was?  If there is only one table referenced in the sql then the issue is irrelevant, if there are two or more referendced in the From clause, then there is no way for the SQL query processor to determine which you want to call as "Current" from any place in the SQL statement except by a) the columnname is only in one table, or B) by using a tablename or table alias qualifier.

Comment: Sorry Charles, my terminology may be incorrect.  When I say 'current table', I mean the table we are building in the current SELECT clause as opposed to the named tables we have in the FROM clause.

Comment: @Rob: What you describe is not possible in SQL for a very specific reason. in a SELECT list, all columns are to de calculated (created, resolved) at the **same time** or **as if they were calculated (created, resolved) at the same time**.

Comment: Or in other words, produce the same result in whatever order they are calculated. Which means no column calculation can be used or referenced in another column's calculation.

Comment: If it was possible, how should the result of this be calculated: `SELECT SUM(a)*sb AS sa, SUM(b)*sa AS sb FROM aTable` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually, this is what I do on these cases:

```
SELECT revenue, 
       units, 
       revenue / units AS revperunit2 
FROM   (SELECT SUM(revenue) AS revenue, 
               SUM(units)   AS units 
        FROM   inputtable) subsel
```

Sometimes you have complicated queries and re-declaring the fields is not good for readability  neither is for performance. Sub queries is the way to go.

Comment: That's one way I've used to resolve this issue, but it adds some unnecessary redundancy.  Thanks for the help though!

Comment: @Rob Not to disappoint you but most RDBMS will **not** provide the feature you are looking for the way you want it. IFAIK, it's not provided by any RDBMS, but, of course, I can be wrong

Comment: I suggest the OP look at the query plan to see if the RDBMS is smart enough to not do the SUMs twice each. If it's wasting CPU on that, this solution is definitely the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

What you describe is not possible in SQL for a very specific reason. In a `SELECT` list, all columns are to de calculated (created, resolved) at the same time or as if they were calculated (created, resolved) at the same time. Or in other words, produce the same result in whatever order they are calculated.

Which means no column alias can be used (referenced) in another column's calculation.

If what you describe was possible, we could have circular references of the type:

```
SELECT SUM(a)*sb AS sa
     , SUM(b)*sa AS sb 
FROM aTable
```

which off course should be rejected as an error. And that would be rather easy by adding a level in the query parser that checks for circular references (exists circular reference: reject query)

But how should the result of this be calculated:

```
SELECT SUM(a) AS b
     , SUM(b) AS a
FROM aTable
```

or why should it be rejected?

If there are no columns `a` and `b` in the table, OK, that would be easy, (exists circular reference: reject query). But if there are columns `a` and `b`, is it a circular reference or not? Is `b` in `SUM(b)` an ambiguous reference? Does it refer to column `b` or to alias `b` ?

---

The second is a valid SQL query, by the way. Because SQL assumes that all calculations are done (`SUM(a)` and `SUM(b)` here) and then the aliases are assigned to the results. It's the same with:

```
UPDATE aTable
SET a=b
  , b=a
```

which actaully swaps data in the two columns. When you write it this way, it's not very clear, until you try it out. There's an alternative prettier way that gives better the idea of what is happening in the background (not all RDBMS support this yet):

```
UPDATE aTable
SET (a,b)=(b,a)
```